# IllegalStateException: Committed ; Committed before 500 org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException

Tags: rest, jetty, solaris, illegalstateexception, eofexception

I am getting this below error when I checked the jetty logs.
From the posts on ther sites, it seems that the solaris response was too slow for the client and it's trying to send a response back to someone 
who's no longer listening for one.

Please let me know if anybody has any idea regarding this. Thanks in advance.

```
    2014-08-01 10:10:08.377:WARN:oejs.Response:qtp136272369-10006: Committed before 500 org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
2014-08-01 10:10:08.378:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp136272369-10006: /estore-web/dec/ret/admin/session/getSessionObject/16019
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:353)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:71)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleFailure(SynchronousDispatcher.java:262)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleWriterException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleWriteResponseException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:203)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:504)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1515)
    at com.tme.user.management.security.filter.BearerTokenAuthenticatingFilter.doFilter(BearerTokenAuthenticatingFilter.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1495)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1097)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1031)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, it says: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host Some reasons:

1. Bad network connection
2. Host shutdown
3. Time-outs
4. Bottle-neck with data overload
5. Intranet: Changed ip without changing intranet DNS

I am having the same exception. What were you trying to do when was it thrown?